# Trying to inline edit an article and submit the values

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to inline edit an article and submit the values from the form. However, the `v-model` values are empty on submit.

Check out my code below. So the top form is for new articles only. And in my `v-for` there's a switch between 'view' and 'edit' mode.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Articles</h2>
    <hr />
    <form class="mb-3" @submit.prevent="addArticle">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Title" v-model="article.title" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Bodytext" v-model="article.body"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-block">Add new</button>
    </form>
    <hr />
    <div class="card card-body mb-2" v-for="article in articles" v-bind:key="article.id">
      <template class="article-row" v-if="edit === article.id">
        <form @submit.prevent="editArticle">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Title" v-model="article.title" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Bodytext" v-model="article.body"></textarea>
          </div>
          <!-- <input type="hidden" v-model="article.id" /> -->
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-block">Update</button>
        </form>
      </template>
      <template v-else>
        <h3>{{ article.title }}</h3>
        <p v-html="article.body"></p>
        <hr />
        <div>
          <button @click="toggleEditMode(article.id)" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button>
          <button @click="deleteArticle(article.id)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      articles: [],
      article: {
        id: "",
        title: "",
        body: ""
      },
      article_id: "",
      edit: false
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.fetchArticles();
  },

  methods: {
    fetchArticles(page_url) {
      let vm = this;
      page_url = page_url || "/api/articles";
      fetch(page_url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          this.articles = res.data;
          vm.makePagination(res.meta, res.links);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    },
    addArticle() {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.article));
      fetch("/api/article", {
        method: "post",
        body: JSON.stringify(this.article),
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json"
        }
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.article.title = "";
          this.article.body = "";
          alert("Article added!", "success");
          this.fetchArticles();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    },
    editArticle() {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.article));
      fetch("/api/article", {
        method: "put",
        body: JSON.stringify(this.article),
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json"
        }
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          alert("Article updated!", "success");
          this.fetchArticles();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    },
    toggleEditMode(article_id) {
      this.edit = article_id;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.article));` on the first line of the `editArticle` function returns an empty object (the default value)... What am i doing wrong?

Comment: In this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/jfrob572/1/) it works.

Comment: @Core972 i'm talking about the editArticle method, not the addArticle

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `article` befeore trying to update it like that:

```
toggleEditMode(article_id) {
  for (let index = 0; index < this.articles.length; index++) {
    const article = this.articles[index];
      if(article.id === article_id){
        this.article = article;
        break;
      }
  }
  this.edit = article_id;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/jfrob572/2/)